# How to get the date difference between START & END dates as a separate column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table, where I have START & END DATE, I want the difference of these date as column, rest other columns can be same for all these rows.

Data :

[image]

The output expected is:

[image]

Please suggest how I can handle this data.

Comment: I don't see any date differences in any column in your output.  What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi Tim, the additional column MonthYear is expected in output which is based on START & END columns. I tried using level/connect by level function.

Comment: @Vin, Please post your effrots and make a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a row generator. For example:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, qty, status, start_date, end_date) as
  2    (select 100, 345, 'Y', date '2023-01-01', date '2023-03-15' from dual union all
  3     select 105, 784, 'N', date '2023-11-07', date '2024-01-28' from dual
  4    )
```

Query (with dates in DD.MM.YYYY format):

```
  5  select t.*,
  6    to_char(add_months(start_date, column_value - 1), 'mm.yyyy') monthyear
  7  from test t cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= ceil(months_between(end_date, start_date))
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

        ID        QTY S START_DATE END_DATE   MONTHYE
---------- ---------- - ---------- ---------- -------
       100        345 Y 01.01.2023 15.03.2023 01.2023
       100        345 Y 01.01.2023 15.03.2023 02.2023
       100        345 Y 01.01.2023 15.03.2023 03.2023
       105        784 N 07.11.2023 28.01.2024 11.2023
       105        784 N 07.11.2023 28.01.2024 12.2023
       105        784 N 07.11.2023 28.01.2024 01.2024

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @littlefoot, There was a slight change I did in your code and it is giving me right number of months
ceil(months_between(end_date, start_date) + 1)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is as follow:

```
select *,
       to_char(start + (generate_series(0,
                                ((DATE_PART('year', "end") -
                                  DATE_PART('year', start)) * 12 +
                                 (DATE_PART('month', "end") -
                                  DATE_PART('month', start)))::int)::text
           || ' month')::interval, 'MON-YY') as diff
from test
order by id;
```

The output is

```
+---+---+------+----------+----------+------+
|id |qty|status|start     |end       |diff  |
+---+---+------+----------+----------+------+
|100|345|true  |2023-01-01|2023-03-15|JAN-23|
|100|345|true  |2023-01-01|2023-03-15|FEB-23|
|100|345|true  |2023-01-01|2023-03-15|MAR-23|
|105|784|false |2023-11-07|2024-01-28|NOV-23|
|105|784|false |2023-11-07|2024-01-28|DEC-23|
|105|784|false |2023-11-07|2024-01-28|JAN-24|
+---+---+------+----------+----------+------+
```

However, it works for Postgres and probably needs to be tuned for Oracle.

Comment: From my point of view, that's pretty much useless in Oracle. There's no GENERATE_SERIES (nor anything like that), DATE_PART, "::int" or "::text" or "::interval" so - how would you exactly *tune* it, if everything but major keywords (SELECT, FROM and such) simply doesn't exist in Oracle?